# Form url in Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, spree

In my ruby application there is a form in the cart page for checkout .

```
= form_for @order, url: update_cart_path, html: { id: 'update-cart', class: 'edit-cart'} do |order_form|


    %div{ data: { hook: 'inside_cart_form'}}
    %div{ data: { hook: 'cart_items' }, style: 'margin-bottom: 20px' }
    = render :partial => 'form', :locals => { :order_form => order_form }
    ----------
    ----------
    ----------
    .row
    .col-sm-4
    = button_tag class: 'btn btn-primary btn-block', id: 'checkout-link', name: 'checkout' do
    = Spree.t(:checkout)
```

Here, the form url is given as 'update_cart_path', But i cannot found a function named like this in the controller ...

I am newbie in ruby..

Please help me to solve this issue ...

## config/routes.rb

```
xxxxx::Application.routes.draw do
  # We ask that you don't use the :as option here, as Spree relies on it being the default of "spree"
  mount Spree::Core::Engine, at: '/'
  mount MailPreview, at: 'mail_view' if Rails.env.development?

  Spree::Core::Engine.routes.draw do
    get  'measure' => 'home#measure'
    get  'about' => 'home#about'
    get  'sizes' => 'orders#sizes'
    get  'paypal' => 'paypal#express', as: :express_paypal
    get '/products/:id/:variant_name' => 'products#show', as: :product_variant_detail

    resources :variants, only: [] do
      get :carousel
      get :description
    end

    resources :orders do
      member do
        post 'increase', defaults: { format: 'json' }
        post 'decrease', defaults: { format: 'json' }
      end
      collection do
        put 'add_coupon_code'
      end
    end

    namespace :admin do
      resources :blog_entries, only: [] do
        resources :blog_entry_images, except: [:index, :show]
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: `update_cart_path ` is not a function in any controller. It is the path rails construct based on your `routes` configuration. Do run `rake routes` to get full list of controller path and respective controller with actions.

Comment: @AshikSalman, I have updated my question with routes.rb file..

Answer (score 1):

Go to your console and run

```
rake routes
```

you will see all routes like this:

```
prefix      verb  URL        crontroller#action
update_cart patch /your/url  carts#update
            put   /your/url  carts#update
```

in this way you will get to know what is this url for and for which action and which controller. alternatively you can also check your `config/routes.rb`.

hope this will help you.

Comment: @Cliffs incase if you are using spree gem you need to clone spree code and there you will see this action and controller and incase you want to this action and controller in your project then you will need to create a decorator of that controller and action.

Comment: @Cliffs just clone it `git@github.com:spree/spree.git` you will see here.

Comment: It has been already cloned with the spree code and have a order_controller_decorator.rb file as , https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/master/frontend/app/controllers/spree/orders_controller.rb

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168175/discussion-between-gabbar-and-cliffs).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to customize spree behavior you have two options:

**1)** For example, if we have a controller file named:

```
test_controller.rb
```

then decorator file name would be:

```
test_controller_decorator.rb
```

So, if we have following controller from Spree:

```
\app\controllers\spree\products_controller.rb
```

we can create following decorator in our project:

```
\app\controllers\spree\products_controller_decorator.rb
```

Now, we add following code:

```
module Spree
  Spree::ProductsController.class_eval do

     # copy and paste existing actions here and customize

  end
end
```

**2)** Create the same file in the same directory and copy/paste from the source code and customize.

The file you are looking for is here: [https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/master/frontend/config/routes.rb](http://%20spree/frontend/config/routes.rb)